# Meta Definition for SPA pages

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, meta, googlebot

I have a SPA project (AngularJS). I build my project for each customer separately. When google robots crawl my web page, they just crawl source code then, source code indexed in search result. But if I say fetch and render from webmaster tools every things OK! Google indexed the rendered code and show it in search result. I wonder that. Is there any meta definition to say "Hey google fetch and render this page"? Such as :

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,render">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researh it and found fregment meta. Google understands that This site loads its content by Ajax, thanks of this meta. 
Usage:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Details: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification